# Setting SharePoint 2013 Ribbon Button Click event on XML

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin

I have the below script for adding a formatted `<H3>` and `<p>` element into a SharePoint site page in edit mode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("button[name='addDom']").click(function() {
        var domElement = $('<div><h3>Heading</h3></br><p>Text</p></div>');
        $(this).after(domElement);
    });

});
</script>
```

on the button click:

```
<button name="addDom" type="button">Click</button>
```

May I know how to incorporate this button click into the below XML file, so that when I click on the custom ribbon button, I am able to add the `<h3>` and `<p>` element to the site page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<branding xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">    
  <customaction  Name="InsertRibComponentUI" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" Sequence="30" removeCustomAction="false">
    <commandUIExtension>
        <![CDATA[<CommandUIExtension>
                <CommandUIDefinitions>
                    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.Controls._children">
                         <Button
                            Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.RibUI"
                            Command="Ribbon.Command.InsertRibComponentUI"
                            Sequence="30"
                            Image16by16="/_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap16x16.png?rev=33" Image16by16Left="-164" Image16by16Top="-270"
                            Image32by32="/_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=33" Image32by32Left="-102" Image32by32Top="-341"
                            Description="Insert Ribbon Button"
                            LabelText="Button"
                            TemplateAlias="o1" />
                    </CommandUIDefinition>
                </CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIHandlers>
                        <CommandUIHandler
                            Command="Ribbon.Command.InsertRibComponentUI"
                            CommandAction="javascript:alert('Test');"/>
                </CommandUIHandlers>
            </CommandUIExtension>]]>
    </commandUIExtension>
  </customaction>
</branding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is syntax to execute a javascript on clicking button on ribbon

```
CommandAction="javascript:
          function loadHtml() {
                 var domElement = $('<div><h3>Heading</h3></br><p>Text</p></div>');
                 $(this).after(domElement);
           }
           loadHtml();"
```

You can read this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458385.aspx) for complete details about custom action button

This is working with SharePoint on-premises. You can also try for SharePoint online.

Comment: @VenkalKonjeti,  i gave like the below: <CommandUIHandler
                 Command="Ribbon.Command.InsertRibComponent"
                                     CommandAction="javascript:
          function loadHtml() {
                 var domElement = $('div><h3>Heading</h3></br><p>Text</p></div>');
                 $(this).after(domElement);
           }
           loadHtml();"/>
              </CommandUIHandlers>         But i am getting An unhandled exception with Additional information: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 20, position 42.

Comment: I think that might be a problem because you have HTML inside the XML. You can keep the javascript function in external JS file and call that function. Refer example here http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/21/referencing-external-javascript-when-building-custom-sharepoint-2010-ribbon/